# Puppeteer click function after $$.eval

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chromium

I would like to download images which I search on google using Puppeteer. However after I click the images buttons, below `$.eval` functions are not working. It said `failed to find element matching selector div[jsname="I4bIT"]` . I wonder if clicking something using `$$.eval` change the page instance? Thank you very much in advance.

```
async function findAndDownloadImage(page, elem = 'hello') {
    try {
        await page.goto(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${elem}+expression`);

        await page.$$eval('.HF9Klc.iJddsb', elem => elem[1].click()); //click picture button

        await page.$eval('div[jsname="I4bIT"]', clickAction); //click tool button
        await page.$eval('div[aria-label="大小"]', clickAction); //click sizeButton 
        await page.$eval('a[aria-label="大"]', clickAction); //click largeOption 

        
        await page.$eval('.rg_i.Q4LuWd', clickAction); //click 1st image

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait after the first click until the image-search tab's elements are loaded into the DOM. It can be achieved with [`page.waitForSelector`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options):

```js
await page.$$eval('.HF9Klc.iJddsb', elem => elem[1].click()); //click picture button
await page.waitForSelector('div[jsname="I4bIT"]'); //wait for image-search tab loaded v1
await page.$eval('div[jsname="I4bIT"]', clickAction); //click tool button
...
```

...or [`page.waitForNavigation`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions):

```js
await page.$$eval('.HF9Klc.iJddsb', elem => elem[1].click()); //click picture button
await page.waitForNavigation(); //wait for image-search tab loaded v2
await page.$eval('div[jsname="I4bIT"]', clickAction); //click tool button
...
```